# Jclouds - Neutron specify a nic when associating a floating ip

Tags: networking, ip, openstack, jclouds

I create instances with multiple network interfaces. However when I associate an floating ip to the instance as below, floating ip is always get allocated to the first interface of the instance.

```
api.addToServer(ip, server-id);
```

How do I get the floating ip assigned to the second or an interface other than the first interface. I could not find a way of specifying a nic when associating an floating ip.

I tried a different approach using Openstack commandline and seems it is working.

```
neutron floatingip-create ext
neutron floatingip-associate floating_ip-id port-id
```

However I could not find a way to associate a floating ip to a port also.

Then starting the instance with the port-id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floating IP extension for Neutron is not supported as of right now 8/20/14 in jclouds.

Comment: Could you point me to any specific place in code to create a patch

Comment: Support has been added in master. Check https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs-openstack/tree/master/openstack-neutron/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/neutron/v2

Answer (score 0):

Is this feature available in JClouds latest release 1.8.1.

Thanks !